# is there anyway to find the ad loading time using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I am working an project where i need the **starting time** when an ad request made and **end time** when ad is completely  loaded. So that i can compute latency time for ad. I am using **google dfp** and **doubleclick**.

**UPDATE:**
i don't want to call my website from external library like Phantomjs . I want some javascript solution so that i can edit my js files and get the latency time for ad loading. Thanx

Comment: Which mehod are you using for loading defineSlot or  display or addService() ?

Comment: guys the problem is solved ....

Comment: you didn't mark an answer or provide one of your own though, and your bounty expires in 4 minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you get the current time right before you send the request and the current time right after you finish loading it and subtract those times?

```
var timeAfter;
var timeBefore = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
//make requests //
function callBack(){
    // Completely load ad//
    timeAfter = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
}
var latency = timeAfter - timeBefore;
```

That's in seconds, but you can play with the math and get milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try using PhantomJS.

It's a headless browser. You can use it like a browser, but programatically and get info from it.

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS, CasperJS, or write a node script.  If you're doing this more ad hoc in the browser, having the network tab open when the page loads should tell you how long the request took.

Answer (score 2):

Describing the basic method, as you didn't give any code.

In the function that loads the ad, set a variable with current milliseconds (eg startTime = Date.now())

Then depending on the media you are loading, you can use the onload event (for images) or the loadstart and loadeddata events for video, adio, etc. If it's called via XHR, then you should already have a load event to insert the ad into the dom. Grab Date.now() once more, and subtract the startime from it.

There's your load time.

Comment: it should be comment not answer

Comment: @nitin-kumar I would have commented, but I wasn't able to "comment everywhere" at the time. Ironically this up-vote is what gave me the privilege. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the chrome dev tools. Use `cntr`+`shift`+`i` in your browser and navigate to timeline or network

You can't use the tools to call a function in your JS code, but it's a pretty nice view on the speed of your side.

Answer (score 0):

Answers for this Question is already available stack itself.

Please refer these links. those might be answer for question hopefully.

[Calculating Page Load Time In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript)

[Page load time with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045767/page-load-time-with-javascript)

[What is the best way to measure Client Side page load times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547458/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-client-side-page-load-times)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like the [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).  AppNexus's Headerbid Expert Chrome extension is a great example of how this can be used to examine network traffic.  You're probably going to need to roll your own pattern matchers for network traffic based on the demand side, but maybe you can get clever and parse "doubleclick.net" traffic to automate that process.  [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) and [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) each have their own way of doing this.

If a plug-in isn't what you're looking for, then you can simply [overwrite request prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406606/can-jquery-listen-to-ajax-calls-from-other-javascript).  You'll tend to find examples of this kind of code in javascript test tools, such as [Sonin](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server-api).  There you'll typically also find examples of timing things.